# Cartthrob not saving purchased items when order created

Tags: cartthrob, mightybigrobot

As the title states, when an order is placed, the order items should appear as entries in the Purchased Items channel but they do not.

The config is all set up as expected.

EE 2.7.2, CT Pro 2.4

Comment: Update to CT 2.5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this issue too, with CT Pro 2.4 and EE 2.7.3

- Orders are appearing in the order channel.
- Order items are appearing in the purchased channel

however the order_items field in the order has no rows to connect them.

Comment: Hey Chris, just commented on the original q, can you update to CT 2.5?

Comment: This isn't an answer, please delete.